# How to skip the dot (.) and dotdot (..) in FindNextFileW?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm using `FindNextFileW` to successfully list the files in a directory. The problem is that it references itself, current directory, with `.` and parent directory with `..`. I'm trying to skip these using an `if` condition but it still prints them.

**Code:**

```
int wmain() {

WIN32_FIND_DATAW data;
std::wstring dir = L"c:\\* ";
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(dir.c_str(), &data);

if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    do {
        wchar_t dot[] = L"." ;
        wchar_t dotd[] = L"..";

        if ( data.cFileName != dot && data.cFileName != dotd)
        std::wcout << data.cFileName << std::endl;
    } while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &data));
    FindClose(hFind);
}
return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to skip the printing of `.` and `..` by using an `if` condition. However, it still prints them. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

**EDIT:**

This question is not about how `wchar_t` arrays cannot be compared. That is good to know but ultimately my question is about how to skip the `.` and `..` in `FindNextFileW`. I have tried converting to `std::wstring` but then I can define:

```
std::wstring dot = '.';
std:wstring dotd = '..';
```

But how do I check them against `cFilename`?

Comment: Arrays of any type are not comparable  with the built-in operators.

Comment: `SIZE_T FileNameLength = wcslen(data.cFileName);

    switch (FileNameLength)
    {
    case 2:
     if (data.cFileName[1] != '.') break;
    case 1:
     if (data.cFileName[0] == '.') continue;
    }`

Comment: _"This question is not about how wchar_t arrays cannot be compared"_ That's exactly what it's about. What the `wchar_t` arrays contain is irrelevant, and therefore `FindNextFileW` (and the Windows API in general) are also irrelevant. Divide and conquer. Reduce your problem.

Comment: It's a duplicate many times over. You skip these items by performing string comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```
if (wcscmp (data.cFileName, dot) != 0 && wcscmp (data.cFileName, dotd) != 0)
    ...
```

Note also that:

```
wchar_t dot[] = L"." ;
```

should be:

```
const wchar_t dot[] = L"." ;
```

and likewise for `dotd`.

If using C++17, you might also like to look into [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem)

Comment: really here can be more efficient code, compare strcmp, but of course this is also ok

Comment: Why even `[]` not `*`; no need for a copy

Comment: In fact you _may_ want to take the shortcut that accidentally led to the "hidden files" convention on Linux (though I realise this is for Windows), and just check the first character for being `L'.'`. Depends what you need to do though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Windows allows directory and file names to begin with `.`, and I have seen many apps take advantage of that, like Minecraft, TortoiseSVN, etc

Comment: @RemyLebeau The apps you list surely make use of leading `.` in the same way as they would on Linux (even though it's not a Windows convention in the truest sense; find a native tool that cares about leading `.`!) What I'm saying is that it is up to the OP as to whether they want to adopt this convention in their app or not; if they do, they can simplify this logic substantially.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _Why even `[]` not `*`; no need for a copy_ - I didn't read it very carefully - I thought it _was_ `.`!

Comment: What I mean is that, by using `[]`, the OP is copying the string literal into a local array when they don't need to. Just `const wchar_t* dot = L".";` will do fine

Answer (score 6):

You are just comparing the pointers and they will never be the same. `data.cFileName` is not a `std::[w]string`, it is just a plain C-style string.

You could use `lstrcmpW()`, but these are so short you don't even have to do that, just check the characters manually or use a helper function:

```
template<class T> bool IsDotOrDotDot(const T*s)
{
  if (s[0] == T('.'))
  {
    if (s[1] == T('\0')) return true; // .
    if (s[1] == T('.') && s[2] == T('\0')) return true; // ..
  }
  return false;
}

...

do {
  if (!IsDotOrDotDot(data.cFileName))
  {
    ...
  }
} while (...);
```

Comment: Not sure what the purpose of the template is when your char-type is hardcoded, but otherwise good.